# Discrepancy between specified and observed pseudorandom number generation

Tags: java, random

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException{
    Random r = new Random(1);
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        int n = r.nextInt(10);
        System.out.print(n+" ");

    }
}
```

The result is :

> 5 8 7 3 4 4 4 6 8 8

I already look to [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)  the formula for updating seed is

```
(seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
```

which in this case is equal `0x5DEECE678L` in my case

and returning

```
(int)(seed >>> (48 - bits))
```

and if we use 
public int nextInt(int bound)

the result should be 4

Comment: The beauty of open source is that the source is there for all to see: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Random.java#Random.nextInt%28%29

Comment: This was inappropriately closed because OP quotes the documentation and his observed discrepancy. No source code inspection should be involved in a question about specified behavior.

Comment: You are missing the fact that the `new Random(1)` constructor call itself changes the seed from 1L according to `(seed ^ 0x5DEECE66DL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)`. See the Javadoc where they say "The invocation new Random(seed) is equivalent to: Random rnd = new Random(); rnd.setSeed(seed);" and [setSeed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed-long-)